# How to show image 15 seconds, while data loading to the app?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, screen, seconds

I am making an app and i am using sqlite database. On the first launch of my application and on its onUpdate, i am add data to sqlite db from the xml file. Consequently, on the first launch of my app, it shows me  white screen ~15 seconds. I want to show my full screen), ~15 seconds.  How i can do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `SplashActivity` display your Image, use `Hander.postDelayed()` to delay this screen 15s before startActivity to main screen.

Here is example:

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

    /** Duration of wait **/
    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 15000;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

        /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity 
         * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/

        //Load data

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
                Splash.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                Splash.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: And how to do that on the FIRST LAUNCH of my application?

Comment: Splash is an activity. You must set it to MAIN an AndroidManifest

Comment: your code isnt helped me, when i start MainActivity using intent,

Comment: your code isnt helped me. I still need to wait 15 seconds on the empty MainActivity, while i launch it.

Comment: Did you set MAIN and LAUNCHER to Splash activity on manifest and remove them on MainActivity ?

Comment: And put the code load to splash, add image to content view of splash

Comment: ok, but it is done every time I launch the app. But i want to show image only on the first launch of app.

Comment: ok, but it is done every time I launch the app. But i want to show image only on the first launch of app.

Comment: ok but it is done every time I launch the app. But i want to show image only on the first launch of app.

Comment: HOW i can do that

Comment: ok, but it is done every time I launch the app. But i want to show image only on the first launch of app.

Comment: You should use SharePreference to save an flag mark with the first launcher, that flag will check when your app laucher.